# How is it that the documented intent states in Lex are different from the actual available values?What is the difference between each of these states?

Tags: aws-lambda, amazon-lex

I am currently working on integrating aws Lex with lambda function written in TypeScript and I am facing a situation in which I need help .

**Upon reading the aws documentation for LexV2 the following values are available for an intent state:**

- Failed
- Fulfilled
- FulfillmentInProgress
- InProgress
- ReadyForFulfillment
- Waiting

**However when I used the 'Waiting' value, The following error message showed up :**

> Invalid Lambda Response: Received invalid response from Lambda: Can not deserialize value of type Intent$IntentState from String "Waiting": value not one of declared Enum instance names: [ReadyForFulfillment, InProgress, Failed, Fulfilled]

**Upon this I need help to:**

1. Understand how is it possible to have values that are not recognized.
2. Understand the difference between each of these values (*Note: not all of the accepted values are explained in the documentation*)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reaching out to aws support here is the answer:

LexV2 doesn't  accept "FulfillmentInProgress" or "Waiting" as valid intent state.

Difference between each of the valid value:

> ReadyForFulfillment - The bot is ready to fulfillment. Passing this state via lambda output will make the bot jump to fulfillment state

> InProgress - The default state

> Fulfilled - The bot will jump to closed state and will play back both the fulfillment success message and closing response

> Failed - Mark the intent as failed; will result in bot playing the
> fulfillment failure message